# Issue with CSS and table borders

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to make a grid with a blue background that has 10x10 tiles. All the tiles need to be square, and they need to be filled with blue, with a small black line seperating each tile. When I am formatting the table in CSS, it has edges that are too wide, which is an a minor, yet fairly irratating issue. I cannot see what the issue is, can anyone else?

```js
var boatStatusClient = "";
var x_client = 0;
var y_client = 0;
var battlefield_client = "";

var source_client;
var boatGrid = {
  placeBoat_client: function() {
    source_client = event.target || event.srcElement;
    source_client = source_client.id
    source_client.id = document.getElementById(source_client.id);
    document.getElementById(source_client).style.backgroundColor = "orange";

  },
}

for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
  battlefield_client += "<tr>";
  for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
    battlefield_client += "<td onclick = '' class = 'tile' style='border: 3px solid black;' id=" + "cell_client_" + x_client + "_" + y_client + ">&nbsp</td>";
  }
  battlefield_client += "</tr>";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tableGrid_client").html(battlefield_client); //loads table

  for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
    for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
      boatStatusClient = document.getElementById('cell_client_' + x_client + "_" + y_client);
      boatStatusClient.addEventListener("click", function() {
        boatGrid.placeBoat_client()
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}
.tile {
  background-color: #34B0D9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tile:hover {
  background-color: #6fcdec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hideGames">
  <table style="position:absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; border:6px solid #ff5050; width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="tableGrid_client"></table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add [`table-layout:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to your `table`

> **fixed**
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can
>   speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but
>   subsequent cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any
>   cell that has content that overflows uses the overflow property to
>   determine whether to clip the overflow content.

**Note:** avoid inline styles.

```js
    var boatStatusClient = "";
    var x_client = 0;
    var y_client = 0;
    var battlefield_client = "";

    for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
      battlefield_client += "<tr>";
      for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
        battlefield_client += "<td onclick = '' class = 'tile' style='border: 3px solid black;' id=" + "cell_client_" + x_client + "_" + y_client + ">&nbsp</td>";
      }
      battlefield_client += "</tr>";
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tableGrid_client").html(battlefield_client); //loads table

      for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
        for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
          boatStatusClient = document.getElementById('cell_client_' + x_client + "_" + y_client);
          boatStatusClient.addEventListener("click", function() {
            boatGrid.placeBoat_client()
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 118%;
  font-family: calibri light;
  background-color: #E8E8E8
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 6px solid #ff5050;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.tile {
  background-color: #34B0D9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tile:hover {
  background-color: #6fcdec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <!--START OF GAMES PART-->
  <div class="hideGames">
    <table style="" id="tableGrid_client"></table>
  </div>
  <!--END OF GAMES PART -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what the table-layout: fixed function is, and why it works?

Comment: answer is updated, take a look. If this solves your issue make sure you mark the answer as accepted.